# Ubuntu ec2 instance fails to run userdata script

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, aws-code-deploy, cloud-init

I am trying to execute a script which needs to be run on Ubuntu 14.04 ec2 instance whenever the instance or it's image in auto scaling group spins up-

```
#!/bin/bash-x
REGION=`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-    identity/document|grep region|awk -F\" '{print $4}'`
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
cd
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ruby-2.3.1.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.3.1/
./configure
make
sudo make install
apt-get install apache2 
cd /home/ubuntu  
wget https://aws-codedeploy-$REGION.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
./install auto
```

But the script never runs. I went to cloud-init-output.log file and following is the log details-

```
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Mon, 12 Dec 2016 15:54:20 +0000. Up 36.92 seconds.
2016-12-12 15:54:20,432 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running     /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [-]
2016-12-12 15:54:20,436 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2016-12-12 15:54:20,436 - util.py[WARNING]: Running scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scrip$
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 finished at Mon, 12 Dec 2016 15:54:20 +0000.     Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 37.11 seconds
```

Specifically, I am trying to achieve is to install codedeploy in the instance.

Comment: Check if the first line is the culprit: "#!/bin/bash-x"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To test this, I launched an Amazon Linux EC2 instance with `#!/bin/bash-x` at the top of the User Data.

The log said:

```
/bin/sh: /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: /bin/bash-x: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I re-launched it without the `-x` and it worked fine.

So, that is definitely the cause of the problem for Amazon Linux. Things might be different with Ubuntu.

**Update:** As per sqlbot's suggestion (below), I tried it again with `#!/bin/bash -x` (a space before `-x`) and it worked fine.

Comment: The intended value is probably `#!/bin/bash -x` with a space before `-x`. Omitting the space would definitely break it on Ubuntu as well.  FWIW, the `-x` option is verbose mode with expansion -- it causes bash to echo each line before executing it, after variable interpolation.

Comment: The script is running perfectly in my local machine, however, its still not executing on AWS ec2 during startup (userdata).

Comment: User Data scripts only execute when the instance is first launched. It will not run on subsequent instance Starts. Are you passing the User Data while launching a new instance?

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had some extra space at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Better if you place a snippet of what was working for you

Comment: Nothing special, I just had an extra space at the beginning of my bash script and the server failed to run my script. Once I removed the extra space, it worked properly..

Comment: tnx, I spent 2 days for find this suggestion and fix my issue

Answer (score 1):

The shebang you have used is wrong.

Change `#!/bin/bash-x` to `#!/bin/bash`